# Doing a search on metadata using jclouds

Tags: java, jclouds, openstack-swift

I wanted to do a search on my SWIFT storage using metadata of the objects.

For example, if all my objects have metadata of `X-object-Meta-startTime: <value>`
My objective is to search for objects with startTime of, let say, 20.

It is not yet implemented in swift itself: https://blueprints.launchpad.net/swift/+spec/searchable-metadata

Is there such an API in jclouds instead? Is it possible? (I'm using jclouds to interface with swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jclouds cannot provide more than the underlying object store provides and Swift has not yet implemented this feature.  You can call `BlobStore.list` and `BlobStore.blobMetadata` on each result.  Alternatively you can create your own mapping in an external service like a database, e.g., H2 or MySQL.  This corresponds to the second approach in the link you provided.